# Multiple submits change records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

What i want

[image]

I want what when press on button "Change" update records in MySQL, but how to do it? How create submits what page know which submit press and which line need update in MySQL?

Comment: Each button should have its own form and you should have an id on each. Then submit to some page and update the record based on the ID...or you could use JS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button element must has a name attribute eg change.

```html
<button type="button" name="change">Click Me!</button>
```

So you must write the following code:

```html
if(isset($_POST['change'])){
$query="UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...WHERE some_column=some_value ";
$result=mysqli_query($connection_db,$query);
}
```

For multiple buttons use name="change_1" etc..

Comment: But how page know which input is id? Before inputs numbers is id. And then press on Change it's should change only one line records.

Comment: You want to update records with one button or with the corresponding button?Give me an example

Comment: No, I want update with corresponding button. But that update records only this line on which button click.

Comment: So for each input element that you have set an unique name eg input_1. Then assign a variable to value that corresponding in that input element eg $input_1=$_POST['input_1'] and finally execute the code that i wrote before

Comment: It's need forms as much as buttons?

Comment: No make a single form to contain all of these and add method="post"

Comment: But how then input type text set name? eg name_1?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="input_1">

Comment: Correction <input type="text" value="Submit">

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['change'])){
$input_1=$_POST['input_1'];
$query="UPDATE table_name SET column1=$input_1 WHERE some_column=some_value ";
$result=mysqli_query($connection_db,$query);
}
```

Comment: **Warning**: this code contains a SQL injection vulnerability and should not be used verbatim. Always use parameter binding when introducing user-tainted values into your SQL.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) [The same goes for incorrect answers.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

To have a submit button for each row is something needs to be related to the reality, each row has a unique value, like row 1 has a primary key or unique key for the wanted row. If you want to update that specific row, you'll need to write within the update statement `where something = something`.

Each button has an input statement like: `<input name="sub1" type="button">`. the reason that I didn't put submit is because the button type and isset(_$POST("sub1")) will do as same as submit.

Now, each row will have an input with a unique name so when you click on it will perform a different action.

Then, the code that will run after the button was clicked.

```
if (isset($_POST("sub1")){
//calrify theconncetion class if you have or establish a connection
$text1 = $_POST['fieldName']; // you know that each field has a unique name
$text2 = $_POST['fieldName'];
//continue until you grap all data
//the update statement 
$q ="update tablename SET name="$text1" , email="$text2" where something = 1"; // focus on "where" because as I said each row has a unique value and each $_POST['buttonName'] will update a unique row. only change the where segment.
}
```

Comment: **Warning**: this code contains a SQL injection vulnerability and should not be used verbatim. Always use parameter binding when introducing user-tainted values into your SQL.